# How to not get an error when editing data if I will not upload any image in the user

Tags: html, spring-boot

So while I'm updating the data for the user, I ran into an error that even If i already have an image uploaded for the user in my DB, it wants to upload an image again. Can anyone tell me how to save user without uploading image but the uploaded image remains in my DB?

The error is java.IOException: Could not save image file:

caused by: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: profile-image/4

Here's my controller

```
@PostMapping("/profile/save")
public String saveProfile(Profile profile, Model model, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile,@RequestParam(value="userId", required=false) Long userId) throws IOException {
profile.setUser(userRepo.findById(userId).get());
String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()) ;
String uploadDir - "profile-image/"+ profile.getId();
FileUploadUtil.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, multipartFile);
profile.setProfileImg(fileName);
profileService.saveProfile(profile);
return "redirect:/user/profile";
```

Comment: What is `FileUploadUtil`?

Comment: Oh sorry, its a java class, I included it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your `FileUploadUtil` class. You should only create the directory if it **doesn't** exist:

```
public static void saveFile(String uploadir, String fileName, MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);
    if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
    }
    try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
        Path filePath = uploadPath. resolve(fileName);
        System.out.printIn(filePath.toFile()-getAbsolutePath()+"File Path*******");
        Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new IOException("Could not save image file: " + fileName, ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me like a sample code since I only followed the tutorial here: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-tutorial

Comment: Just look at this line `if (!Files.exists(uploadPath))`. There is an exclamation mark before `Files.exists`

Comment: Yes, how can I store file name in a hidden field on the form?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Fill a hidden input dynamically after `change` event is triggered on file input? Maybe you should open another question if you can't find a solution